# How to merge matchers in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

This is my specs:

```
   it "should convert doc successfully" do
      @response = SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.doc"))
      @response[:status].should == 'ok'
      File.exist?(@response[:pdf_path]).should be_true
      File.exist?(@response[:swf_path]).should be_true
      File.exist?(@response[:cover_path]).should be_true
    end

    it "should convert ppt successfully" do
      @response = SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.ppt"))
      @response[:status].should == 'ok'
      File.exist?(@response[:pdf_path]).should be_true
      File.exist?(@response[:swf_path]).should be_true
      File.exist?(@response[:cover_path]).should be_true
    end

    it "should convert xls successfully" do
      @response = SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.xls"))
      @response[:status].should == 'ok'
      File.exist?(@response[:pdf_path]).should be_true
      File.exist?(@response[:swf_path]).should be_true
      File.exist?(@response[:cover_path]).should be_true
    end
```

How to merge repetition ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a custom matcher in a new `conversion_helpers.rb` file:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_converted_successfully do
  match do |conversion_response|
    conversion_response[:status] == 'ok' && File.exist?(conversion_response[:pdf_path]) && File.exist?(conversion_response[:swf_path]) && File.exist?(conversion_response[:cover_path])
  end
end
```

Then in your spec, `require 'conversion_helpers'` and you can do:

```
it "should convert doc successfully" do
  SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.doc")).should be_converted_successfully
end

it "should convert ppt successfully" do
  SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.ppt")).should be_converted_successfully
end

it "should convert xls successfully" do
  SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.xls")).should be_converted_successfully
end
```

Although, in actual testing this could get quite annoying trying to track down a bug. But that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

make it as a function?
put the function description in the describe block

```
def convert_expectation(resp)
  resp[:status].should == 'ok'
  File.exist?(resp[:pdf_path]).should be_true
  File.exist?(resp[:swf_path]).should be_true
  File.exist?(resp[:cover_path]).should be_true
end  

it "should bla blabla" do
  resp = SharpOffice::Office.process(File.expand_path("spec/fixture/test.xls"))
  convert_expectation(resp)
end
```